# Struggling with bitnami/openldap container on docker - how to create ACLs for read write access?

Tags: docker, openldap, bitnami

I am currently struggling with my openldap docker container by bitnami to import ldap acls. I want for example simple read write access for group x under groups from the ou=groups,dc=eample,dc=com.

I alreade created an admin user for login for phpldapadmin and I found out that I need the LDAP-Config Admin for higher privileges. It looks like this:

```
services:
  openldap:
    image: bitnami/openldap:2.6
    container_name: openldap
    environment:
      - LDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
      - LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - "LDAP_ROOT=dc=example,dc=com"
      - LDAP_CONFIG_ADMIN_ENABLED=yes
      - LDAP_PORT_NUMBER=389
      - BITNAMI_DEBUG=false
    volumes:
      - 'openldap_data:/bitnami/openldap'
      - ./ldifs:/ldifs #exchange folder for import acls in this case
  phpldapadmin:
    image: osixia/phpldapadmin:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: phpldapadmin
    environment:
      - PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=openldap
      - PHPLDAPADMIN_HTTPS=false
      - LDAP_ENABLE_TLS=no
    depends_on:
      - openldap

volumes:
  openldap_data:
    driver: local
```

If I try to import acls, I get errors about not finding cn=config or not authenticated. password credentials for config user should be admin admin (in example).

One snippet I tried

dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess

add: olcAccess olcAccess: {0}to dn.subtree="ou=User,dc=example,dc=com"               group.exact="ou=sec_assets,ou=User,dc=example,dc=com" write

Maybe someone can explain me, how to import acls correctly with very simple syntax.
Thank you very much!

Comment: do you resolve this @indi-gp? I am struggling with the same problem

Comment: No, unfortunately not..

Answer (score 1):

my bitnami openldap container (latest) is using a hdb database as default.
Therefore after examining the right dn I'm using following example expression for modifying credentials related to the hdb database:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=1001,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage by * none
```

The opeldap service is running with uid 1001.

U're able to list all Databases and their ACLs with:
`ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config '(objectClass=olcDatabaseConfig)' olcAccess`